# .eslintignore is ignored by create-react-app?

Tags: node.js, eslint, create-react-app

I've placed a `.eslintignore` file in the root of my create-react-app installation, so I can ignore warnings from vendor libs.

It works fine if I run eslint from the commandline:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint src/js/vendor/jquery.js
...warnings ignored...
```

However running `npm start` and `npm run build` seem to ignore the ignore file.

How can I achieve what I want to do here - without editing individual vendor files to add eslint options?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**YES** .eslintignore is ignored. According to [this issue](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2339).

> CRA 1.x+ purposely does not support .eslintignore. Sorry!

**Workarround**

- add `/* eslint-disable */` to the beginning of the file.
- move vendor files into `public/` or use a NPM package.

Comment: Adding /* eslint-disable */ did it for me.  I use webpack's Banner plugin to insert the comment at the top of my transpiled file that was having this issue.

Comment: ...but why? Seems like a strange decision. Does this accomplish anything other than slowing down developers?

Comment: Does the newest version (as of December 2, 2022) still ignore .eslintignore files? I tried putting a file in both my React project src folder and in the main project folder, and it seems that the files I listed for ignoring weren't ignored.

Answer (score 15):

This was fixed with this commit in CRA codebase: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/commit/6f5221c2d7df0b7a097cfdd461967422c3013e12#diff-dc0c4e7c623b73660da1809fc60cf6ba

Simply add `EXTEND_ESLINT=true` to a `.env` file in your project root.

Comment: Which version of react-scripts are you using?

Comment: I use react-scripts: `v3.4.1`

Comment: @ShamilMammadov it works (refer back to the original link in this post), specifically look here, use `.env` file: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/commit/6f5221c2d7df0b7a097cfdd461967422c3013e12#commitcomment-36349315 (...Don't update the scripts in the `package.json`, as @sebbab said, but add the env var in a `.env` file.)

Comment: I just updated @sebbab's answer to correctly reflect the work-around in the link he posted.

Comment: This makes `npm run build` find errors that `npm run lint` doesn't find. This makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work if I exclude complete directories from the .eslintignore in the root. Here is my .eslintignore

```
src/js/vendor/
src/vendor/
```